# How can I use my iPhone 3Gs on T-Mobile?

Tags: ios, jailbreak

Currently my iPhone 3Gs is on iOS 5.01.  I'd like to use it on the T-Mobile network.  What are the steps required to make it happen?

I think it's obvious that I need to jailbreak the phone.  However, googling around around it is unclear whether there is a reliable (untethered) jailbreak for 5.0x.

Do I need to downgrade the OS?  If so, to what version and how?
Any additional steps I need to take?

Comment: Why jailbreak - you just need to unlock and get a Sim <http://www.t-mobile.co.uk/shop/iphone/micro-sim/>  - Which country are you in?

Comment: @Mark I am in US.  Hmmm, can't be that simple?  Really?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tethered jailbreak is available for IOS 5, see [Jailbreak iOS 5 5.0/5.0.1 on iPhone 4 iPod Touch iPad with Redsn0w](http://www.jailbreaknation.com/jailbreak-ios-5-5.0-on-iphone-4-ipod-touch-ipad-with-redsn0w) and of course [blog.iphone-dev.org](http://blog.iphone-dev.org/).

Answer (score 1):

If you are on the stock 5.0.1 firmware, there is no option for you to unlock your iPhone. Ultrasn0w is available for iOS 5(0.1) but you need to have one of these base bands.. 4.26.08, 5.11.07, 5.12.01, 5.13.04, and 6.15.00. The only current supported baseband for iPhone 4 GSM is 1.59.00.

There is no option to downgrade your baseband unfortunately. You can downgrade to iOS 4.3.3, but that won't help your problem.